# How to parse This String "Mon Apr 13 11:33:10 GMT 2015" to java date

Tags: java

```
String date = "Mon Apr 13 11:33:10 GMT 2015";
Date nowDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS yyyy");
Date D1 = null;
D1 = format.parse(date); 
long diff = nowDate.getTime() - D1.getTime(); 
System.out.println("diffffff :" + diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Apr 13 11:33:10 GMT 2015"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong. Use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy",Locale.UK);
```

For more information about the pattern read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You do not have milliseconds, so you have to remove ".SSS" and you have to add the timezone "ZZZ" instead.

Comment: @Raj If it helps you, feel free to accept my answer.